# Como tirar \n na manipulação de arquivos em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho que criar um certo tipo de criptografia. Leio uma String e a mesma é convertida em ASCII e depois escrita em um txt depois em outro código leio esse txt com a string criptografada para poder descriptografa-la. Cada letra seria em uma linha só que para isso é necessário usar o \n. Na hora de ler a string criptografada o \n vem junto. Tem como tirar? Pois preciso do inteiro para realizar a conta para decriptografar.

**Codigo para Criptografar**
     string_1 = 'Gabriel do Prado de Oliveira'

```
 arq = open('cripto.txt', 'a')
 arq.write('\n')


for i in range(len(string_1)):
    cripto = ord(string_1[i])

    cripto = (cripto * 15) / 5

    arq.write(str(cripto))
    arq.write('\n')
```

arq.close()

**Codigo para Descriptografar**

```
arq = open('cripto.txt', 'r')
string_2 = ''
for i in arq:
    aux = (arq.read())
    aux = int(aux)
    final = int((aux / 15) * 5)
    string_2 += chr(final)

arq.close()
print(string_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o *strip*. ex: string_2.strip().